# Knockout.js templates rendering strange linebreaks

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have some nested knockout templates generating menus

The templates may look like this

```
<script id="menu-template" type="text/html">
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'topmenu-template', foreach: $data }" class="nav navbar-nav"></ul>
</script>

<script id="topmenu-template" type="text/html">
    <!-- ko ifnot: Children.length > 0-->
    <li>
        <a data-bind="text: Name + ' x', attr: { href: Url, title: Name }"></a>
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->​
    <!-- ko if: Children.length > 0-->
    <li data-bind="template: { name: 'child-template', foreach: $data }" class="dropdown"></li>
    <!-- /ko -->​
</script>
```

This renders stuff like this

[image]

If I add a content type like `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` it will look like this

[image]

Still way to much whitespace and there is none in the styling. What I've discovered was that there is a `&#8203;` rendered between each `<li>` element. In example

[image]

Any advice how to handle this?

Thanks

**== Update ==**

The rest of the templates

```
<script id="child-template" type="text/html">
    <!--ko if: Level <= 1-->
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-bind="html: Name + ' ' + Level + 'y<b class=\'caret\'></b>', attr: { href: Url, title: Name }" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'childmenu-template', foreach: Children }" class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
    <!--/ko-->​
    <!--ko if: Level > 1-->
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-bind="html: Name + ' ' + Level + 'z<b class=\'caret\'></b>', attr: { href: Url, title: Name }" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'childmenu-template', foreach: Children }" class="" style="white-space: nowrap"></ul>
    <!--/ko-->​
</script>

<script id="childmenu-template" type="text/html">
    <!--ko ifnot: Children.length > 0-->
    <li>
        <a data-bind="text: Level + ' ' + Name, attr: { href: Url, title: Name }"></a>
    </li>
    <!--/ko-->​
    <!--ko if: Children.length > 0-->
    <li data-bind="template: { name: 'child-template', foreach: $data }" class=""></li>
    <!--/ko-->​
</script>
```

Comment: ...and you have double-checked that there are no zero-width space characters in the source, yes?

Comment: Please post your `child-template` html!

Comment: @nemesv Updated with the rest of the templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have zero-width space characters in your source. So you just need to delete them. They are present at the end of each of your closing virtual element comments. Here's what your code looks like in Unicode in a hex editor:

```
0000000330: 002F 006B 006F 0020 │ 002D 002D 003E 200B  /ko -->​
```

Note the `200B` at the end, which is hexadecimal for `8203`.